# error 400 al banear un usuario

Tags: discord.py

estoy desarrollando un bot de discord con la libreria discord.py
al momento de banear a un usuario a veces funciona otras veces no, cuando no funciona me lanza un error de tipo 400 mensaje no se pudo enviar ....

````py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    try:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Ban", description="Recuerda respetar las relgas",
                          timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.add_field(name=f"has sido baneado  de {ctx.guild.name}", value=f"{reason}")
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f" {member.mention} Ha sido Baneado {reason}")

    except:
        await ctx.send(f" a ocurrido un error al banear a  {member}")```
````

Comment: ¿Seguro que es error 400? ¿Probaste a eliminar el `try-except` para ver los tracebacks? Si se trata de un error 400 (te tiene que lanzar `HTTPException` (aunque esto no garantiza que sea 400)) se puede deber a que el contenido de `reason` haga que el mensaje deje de ser válido (por ejemplo, haga que el mensaje se pase del número máximo de caracteres) o a un error externo (por ejemplo, mala conexión).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error 400 es una BAD REQUEST, y las razones pueden ser: por qué al intentar banear al usuario tiene el md/dm cerrado( `embed.add_field(name=f"has sido baneado  de {ctx.guild.name}", value=f"{reason}")`) o un problema de la API de Discord, el problema más bien seria el 2.

Igualmente te dejo aquí el código qué te puede servir y no debería fallar.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
  async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
     await member.ban(reason=reason)
     await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} ha sido baneado con la razón: {reason} ')
```

Saludos.

Comment: La información: Error 400 se puede deber a que no se pudo enviar el mensaje porque el usuario tiene los mensajes directos cerrados es incorrecta. Eso sería Error 403 Forbidden ([API oficial Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#http-http-response-codes) // [`discord.errors.Forbidden` en discord.py (linea 166)](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/errors.py)